# Prevent keypress events from firing in password fields

Tags: javascript, keypress, event-listener

I am working on a script to capture all key presses in a given HTML page.

Right now I have a basic working script

```
document.onkeypress = function(event){
    var evtobj=window.event? event : e;
    if (evtobj.altKey || evtobj.ctrlKey || evtobj.shiftKey)
        console.log("'Alt', 'Ctrl', or 'Shift' key pressed");
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(evtobj.keyCode));
}
```

Now, I want to prevent this function from firing in case the event fired on a password field.

Even though the event fires how should I go on to identify that the `element` is an `input` box and `type` is `password`.

I am guessing it should be done using `event.target`.

Comment: what you can do is when the password field is focus fire a function that contains event.preventDefault(); and as soon as it is out of focus trigger the onkeypress event listener. Also event.preventDefault only works in Firefox, Safari and Chrome. The answer below should work!

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complex

Comment: yea, the answer given below should work great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do by checking the type of the input with `event.target.type` this will return the type the input.

```
<input type="password">
document.onkeypress = function(event){
  if(event.target.type != 'password'){
    var evtobj=window.event? event : e;
    if (evtobj.altKey || evtobj.ctrlKey || evtobj.shiftKey)
        console.log("'Alt', 'Ctrl', or 'Shift' key pressed");
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(evtobj.keyCode));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='password' name='password'/>

document.onkeypress = function(event){
    var containerName = event.target.name;
    if (containerName !== 'password')
    {
        var evtobj=window.event? event : e;
        if (evtobj.altKey || evtobj.ctrlKey || evtobj.shiftKey)
            console.log("'Alt', 'Ctrl', or 'Shift' key pressed");
        console.log(String.fromCharCode(evtobj.keyCode));
    }
 }
```

This should solve your issue